How to create a table with sticky column on left and right, and the body between them is scrollable?
I have been working on a piece of code, trying to achieve the desired layout for a table. However, every time I make adjustments to the code, it causes the table to become distorted or behave unexpectedly. My goal is to have a scrollbar that appears only for the scrollable content within the table, not for the entire table itself. Additionally, I want the scrollbar to be positioned specifically at the bottom of the scrollable content area.


.table-scroll {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 1000px;
}

.table-scroll table {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

.table-scroll th,
.table-scroll td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
}

.table-scroll thead th {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

th.sticky-left,
td.sticky-left {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  background: #ccc;
}

th.sticky-left:nth-child(2),
td.sticky-left:nth-child(2) {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  left: 70px;
  z-index: 10;
  background: #ccc;
}

th.sticky-right,
td.sticky-right {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  background: #ccc;
}
<div class="table-scroll">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="sticky-left w-32" rowspan="2">DATE</th>
          <th class="sticky-left w-32" rowspan="2">DATE2</th>
          <th colspan="10">LINE 1</th>
          <th colspan="10">LINE 2</th>

          <th class="sticky-right" rowspan="2">LINE 3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>SENSOR 1</th>
          <th>SENSOR 2</th>
          <th>SENSOR 3</th>
          <th>SENSOR 4</th>
          <th>SENSOR 5</th>
          <th>SENSOR 6</th>
          <th>SENSOR 7</th>
          <th>SENSOR 8</th>
          <th>SENSOR 9</th>
          <th>SENSOR 10</th>
          <th>SENSOR 1</th>
          <th>SENSOR 2</th>
          <th>SENSOR 3</th>
          <th>SENSOR 4</th>
          <th>SENSOR 5</th>
          <th>SENSOR 6</th>
          <th>SENSOR 7</th>
          <th>SENSOR 8</th>
          <th>SENSOR 9</th>
          <th>SENSOR 10</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="sticky-left w-32">VALUE 1</td>
          <td class="sticky-left w-32">VALUE 1</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 1</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 2</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 3</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 4</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 5</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 6</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 7</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 8</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 9</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 10</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 1</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 2</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 3</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 4</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 5</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 6</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 7</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 8</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 9</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 10</td>
          <td class="sticky-right">VALUE 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="sticky-left w-32">VALUE 2</td>
          <td class="sticky-left w-32">VALUE 2</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 1</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 2</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 3</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 4</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 5</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 6</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 7</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 8</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 9</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 10</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 1</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 2</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 3</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 4</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 5</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 6</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 7</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 8</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 9</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 10</td>
          <td class="sticky-right">VALUE 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="sticky-left w-32">VALUE 1</td>
          <td class="sticky-left w-32">VALUE 1</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 1</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 2</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 3</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 4</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 5</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 6</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 7</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 8</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 9</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 10</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 1</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 2</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 3</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 4</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 5</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 6</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 7</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 8</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 9</td>
          <td>SENSOR DATA 10</td>
          <td class="sticky-right">VALUE 1</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>




for a scrollbar to appear you need to have a scroll container. You can't have a scroll container spanning one or more table columns. I'm afraid you won't be able to do what you want by using tables.

What you have is perfectly usable. And that's as good as it's going to get.

thank you! yes, its good looking for me but the expectation in UI/UX the one on my description T_T

@kiena review my answer and let me know if there's a problem.

Wrap the <table> in a block level element (ex. <div>, <section>, <p>, etc...) and as an option you can assign overflow-x: scroll to the block element which makes the scrollbar always present whether it's actually needed or not. I prefer scroll because it doesn't create shifting like the default value of auto when it pops in and out. Basically any block element can be scrollable and an inline-block element can be scrollable as well if it is styled with white-space: nowrap. Read this post for  further details concerning what's scrollable. What's not scrollable are <table>s and their associated children elements.
The example below consists of 3 <table>s each wrapped in a block element (<section>) The first and last <table> are a single column with a <thead>/<tr>/</th> and 3 <tr><th></th></tr> in the <tbody>. They are the "sticky" elements (more like "fixed", see comments in example). The middle <table> (aka table.content) contains the scrollable content witch consists of 20 columns and, when including the <thead>, 4 rows . Note the scrollbar directly under table.content but not under table.lead or table.last. This layout is very responsive (not designed for mobile though) view it in Full page mode. Further details are commented in the example.


/*
  All lengths in rem units reference the font-size of <html>
  (aka :root). The CSS clap() function has a minimum of 1rem, 
  a maximum of 3rem, and a formula which dynamically changes
  as the viewport width changes because of the 8vw.
*/
:root {
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 8vw - 2rem, 3rem); 
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-family: Consolas;
}

/*
  Flex container keeps the 3 <section>s inline.
*/
main {
  display: flex;
}

/*
  table-layout: fixed makes <table> honor widths set directly
  on any of it's <td> or <th>.
*/
table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  border-collapse: collapsed;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1.51515px groove rgb(128 128 128);
}

th,
td {
  width: 2.5rem;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 2;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background: rgb(183, 183, 183);
}

/*
  Applied to the first column: table.lead and the last column: 
  table.last which takes them out of normal document flow when
  at their designated position (for table.lead it's left: 0 
  and table.last it's right: 0). Notice that the .fixed
  <table>s don't move? The reason why is because they have no 
  sibling elements -- I isolated them by wrapping each in a 
  <section> so now they behave like a fixed element without the 
  limitation of referencing the viewport.
  */
.fixed {
  position: sticky;
}

.lead {
  left: 0;
}

.last {
  right: 0;
}

.scroll {
  max-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.content {
  width: max-content;
}
<main>
  <section>
    <table class="fixed lead">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>COL01</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><th>ROW01</th></tr>
        <tr><th>ROW02</th></tr>
        <tr><th>ROW03</th></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section class="scroll">
    <table class="content">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>COL02</th><th>COL03</th>
          <th>COL04</th><th>COL05</th>
          <th>COL06</th><th>COL07</th>
          <th>COL08</th><th>COL09</th>
          <th>COL10</th><th>COL11</th>
          <th>COL12</th><th>COL13</th>
          <th>COL14</th><th>COL15</th>
          <th>COL16</th><th>COL17</th>
          <th>COL18</th><th>COL19</th>
          <th>COL20</th><th>COL21</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
          <td>DATA</td><td>DATA</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
  <section>
    <table class="fixed last">
      <thead>
        <tr><th>COL22</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr><th>ROW01</th></tr>
        <tr><th>ROW02</th></tr>
        <tr><th>ROW03</th></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
</main>




You can achieve the said requirement by using position: sticky;.
You can refer the following example.


table {
  font-family: "Fraunces", serif;
  font-size: 125%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}
table thead th {
  padding: 3px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 25vw;
  background: white;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}
table td {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

table tbody th {
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: italic;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
}
table thead th:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}
table tbody tr td:first-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}

table thead th:last-child {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}
table tbody tr td:last-child {
  position: sticky;
  right: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 1;
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
}
caption {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}
<main>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>COL02</th>
        <th>COL03</th>
        <th>COL04</th>
        <th>COL05</th>
        <th>COL06</th>
        <th>COL07</th>
        <th>COL08</th>
        <th>COL09</th>
        <th>COL10</th>
        <th>COL11</th>
        <th>COL12</th>
        <th>COL13</th>
        <th>COL14</th>
        <th>COL15</th>
        <th>COL16</th>
        <th>COL17</th>
        <th>COL18</th>
        <th>COL19</th>
        <th>COL20</th>
        <th>COL21</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
        <td>DATA</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>



Hope this helps.
